# blazor pwa can't install

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I Create a new blazorwasm hosted pwa app with the command:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted --pwa
```

This app, when run, can be installed with the (+) sign (in some browsers at least).

But when I started adding/removing files the option (with the (+) sign) disappeared. I thought that the server-worker is what allows the app to be installed, so I didn't touch it. What might have caused that ?

I edited the files wwwroot/css/app.css and wwwroot/index.html (deleted blazor-error-ui).
I deleted bootstrap and font related folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Finally found what was going on. I've deleted the "icons" field in the manifest.json file. Just put an icon it the folder and referenced it in the manifest and I had the (+) sign back.